Why does the B-29 bomber not have propeller control lever in Cockpit/Engineer station
The aircraft of WWII usually had a propeller control lever. But I didn't see the propeller control levers in the flight engineer station.

Related: https://digitalcollections.museumofflight.org/items/show/49678 -- see p.29 in the manual (p.36 in the on-line presentation) -- directions for feathering say that the pilot will push the feathering button -- earlier in the text we find this interesting comment -- "2. Freelance exptrimentation in the B-29 type airplane is hazardous and wasteful. This experimentation must stop."  Fascinating --

As the old saying goes, “regulations are written in blood”. You realize, of course that that was included in the flight manual because, at some point or other, some schmuck decided to play test pilot with a B-29 by experimenting with the prop feathering controls, got out of control and drilled the hole halfway to China.

On the B-29, the feathering switches and manual propeller pitch control switches (marked as "propeller increase and decrease RPM switches" in the diagram) were on the center console in the forward cockpit.

Source: B29 Flight Manual

This shows that there are switches are, but does not really answer the question - why there's no lever?
